# How to get ubuntu default font?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

You know, unity-tweak-tool has a setting for fonts. Default font, Monospace font, Document font and Window title font.

My question is how to get those font names in C?

Comment: These settings sit in dconf in org.gnome.desktop.interface, so look for some dconf library.

Comment: That's true. g_settings_get_string() will return the font name if right parameters specified.

Comment: Since it worked, I've written a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use g_settings_get_string() to get dconf settings from `org.gnome.desktop.interface`.